# Merging Ansible dictionaries

Tags: dictionary, merge, ansible, jinja2

I'm trying to combine two dictionaries with common keys, something like:

```
vpns:
  example:
    vpn_connection_name: "example"
    vpn_client_public_ip: "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
  example2:
    vpn_connection_name: "example2"
    vpn_client_public_ip: "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
```

Plus:

```
vpn_credentials:
  example:
    vpn_shared_key: "somekey"
  example2:
    vpn_shared_key: "someotherkey"
```

To be merged and produce:

```
vpns:
  example:
    vpn_connection_name: "example"
    vpn_client_public_ip: "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
    vpn_shared_key: "somekey"
  example2:
    vpn_connection_name: "example2"
    vpn_client_public_ip: "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
    vpn_shared_key: "someotherkey"
```

Is this possible with Ansible? There's a lot of questions on merging lists or dictionaries, but they're generally about adding more items, rather than combining different properties of the same items.

The reason for needing this is to have the shared keys in a separate vault-encrypted file (I know I could inline encrypt in the same dictionary but unfortunately that's not an option).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using the [combine](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-hashes-dictionaries) filter, like this:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    vpns:
      example:
        vpn_connection_name: "example"
        vpn_client_public_ip: "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
      example2:
        vpn_connection_name: "example2"
        vpn_client_public_ip: "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
    vpn_credentials:
      example:
        vpn_shared_key: "somekey"
      example2:
        vpn_shared_key: "someotherkey"

  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        vpns_new: "{{ vpns|combine(vpn_credentials, recursive=true) }}"

    - debug:
        var: vpns_new
```

The above will output:

```
PLAY [localhost] ******************************************************************************

TASK [set_fact] *******************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "vpns_new": {
        "example": {
            "vpn_client_public_ip": "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx",
            "vpn_connection_name": "example",
            "vpn_shared_key": "somekey"
        },
        "example2": {
            "vpn_client_public_ip": "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx",
            "vpn_connection_name": "example2",
            "vpn_shared_key": "someotherkey"
        }
    }
}

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I'll take this for a spin and see how I go.

Comment: Working flawlessly! Thanks again.